# How to get Service details from multiple servers using batch file and without logging into it

Tags: batch-file

```
REM ***START HERE***
Echo Off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
IF EXIST Result.csv DEL Result.csv
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%L IN (Servers.txt) DO (
   SET ServerName=
   SET ServerName=%%L
   SC.exe \\!ServerName! Query Wuauserv > Result.txt
)
REM ***END HERE***

============================
```

Note:
Issue is some of servers need userid and password authentication, so could any one help me how to Authenticate that. and the details of Services running on  Multiple servers using Batch Command.